# Did git configuration `branch.<name>.fetch` ever exist?

Tags: git, git-config, git-fetch

Git configuration `branch.<name>.fetch` is mentioned in the first [`git-fetch` example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_examples)<sup>1</sup>:

> - Update the remote-tracking branches:
>
>   ```
>   $ git fetch origin
>   ```
>
>   The above command copies all branches from the remote refs/heads/ namespace and stores them to the local refs/remotes/origin/ namespace, unless the branch..fetch option is used to specify a non-default refspec.

But I can't find its doc in [`git-config`'s doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Did `branch.<name>.fetch` ever exist?

Searching in `git-config`'s doc for configs starting with `branch.` or ending with `.fetch`, it seems `branch.<name>.fetch` is a typo of `remote.<name>.fetch`.

<sup>1</sup> This example was added in [commit d504f69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d504f6975d34025ed3b5478b657789410b52cdb1) in 2009.

Comment: "*it seems `branch.<name>.fetch` is a typo of `remote.<name>.fetch`*" Seems you nailed it! Please report to git@vger.kernel.org; see https://github.com/git/git#readme

Comment: The typo fix has been contributed to `git`, currently on `next` branch only, see [a3ca60840b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3ca60840b2a352e3dc02078e733219d0e4f080d). Also see the corresponding [thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAEg0tHSLyaewkgGs0dEXfwQhKmbiO65bXZVU8t7Kn4WwJ1p0Fw@mail.gmail.com/T/#u) in `git.@vger.kernel.org`. I'll vote to close this question.

Comment: emm, I can see no "Close" button. It seems I don't have enough reputation (3,000 according to [Stack Overflow > Help center > Privileges#flag-posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)) to cast a close vote.

Comment: IMO you should create an answer and accept it instead of providing the link to the patch and close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed by both [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040372/did-git-configuration-branch-name-fetch-ever-exist?noredirect=1#comment132423256_75040372) and Junio C Hamano in git mailing list (see the [full thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAEg0tHSLyaewkgGs0dEXfwQhKmbiO65bXZVU8t7Kn4WwJ1p0Fw@mail.gmail.com/T/#u)), Git configuration `branch.<name>.fetch` is indeed a typo.

On Jan 16, 2023, the commit that corrects it to `remote.<repository>.fetch` is merged to "the" `git` repo, currently only on `next` branch, see merge commit [`a3ca60840b`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3ca60840b2a352e3dc02078e733219d0e4f080d).

According to [`git config` doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtfetch), `remote.<repository>.fetch` sets the default `<refspec>` for `git fetch`.  You can find doc for `<refspec>` in [`git fetch` doc, "*Configured Remote-Tracking Branches*"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_configured_remote_tracking_branches).

Since the typo has lasted from 2009 to 2023 (suppose next git release will happen in 2023), there're many copies of full or excerpted `git fetch` docs containing that typo all over the web.  I will try to fix some of them found on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Network, after the next `git` release hence the official `git-fetch` doc adapts the typo fix.

---

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) includes this doc fix:

See [commit ca554bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca554bf36ca198fdc908c225acf838c58c4663d7) (14 Jan 2023) by [Yukai Chou (`muzimuzhi`)](https://github.com/muzimuzhi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 86ccd39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86ccd39a74c228d01361e7a0e8df2e1f1cd0f742), 21 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca554bf36ca198fdc908c225acf838c58c4663d7): fix non-existent config name
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Yukai Chou</sup>

> Replace non-existent `branch.<name>.fetch` to `remote.<repository>.fetch`, in the first example in `git-fetch` doc, which was introduced in [d504f69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d504f6975d34025ed3b5478b657789410b52cdb1) ("modernize fetch/merge/pull examples", 2009-10-21, Git v1.6.6-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f06f3ff76bea09a2344adacca5bfc0d637b2086)).
>
> Rename placeholder `<name>` to `<repository>`, to be consistent with all other uses in git docs, except that `git-config.txt` uses `remote.<name>.fetch` in its "Variables" section.
>
> Also add missing monospace markups.

`git fetch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ca554bf36ca198fdc908c225acf838c58c4663d7/Documentation/git-fetch.txt#L254-L257):

> The above command copies all branches from the remote `refs/heads/`
> namespace and stores them to the local `refs/remotes/origin/` namespace,
> unless the `remote.<repository>.fetch` option is used to specify a
> non-default refspec.